# Filtering ModelForm in django shows empty choice in web form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I am trying to filter some choices by Djangos stock Groups, but when I do so in web form is empty.

If I put Group number directly when filtering, it works. Maybe I have something wrong with arguments?

in views.py I have:

```
class AddSupplier(generic.View):
    form_class = CreateOrder
    template_name = 'order/order_form.html'

    #blank, ce je get metoda
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):

        group = self.request.user.groups.values_list('id', flat=True).first()
        # I tried:
        # group = self.request.user.groups.all() 
        # same result

        form = self.form_class(group, request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            createS = form.save(commit=False)

            supplier = form.cleaned_data['supplier']

            createS.save()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class CreateOrder(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, group,*args,**kwargs):
        super (CreateOrder, self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['supplier'].queryset = Supplier.objects.filter(group_s=group) # if I put group = 1 it works

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = [
            'supplier',
        ]
```

and how thinks are connected in models.py:

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    #...
    group_s = models.ManyToManyField(Group, help_text="kateri dobavitelji imajo katere stranke")
    #...

class Order(models.Model):
    #...
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    #...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not currently including the `group` when you instantiate the form for `get` requests. Try changing the code to:

```
def get(self, request):
    group = self.request.user.groups.values_list('id', flat=True).first()
    form = self.form_class(group, None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: Note that the `values_list()` isn't required. If you used `group = self.request.user.groups..first()` it would work the same.

Comment: great thank you. So if I understand correctly I actually don't need to pass arguments in post just in get?

Comment: No, the `__init__` method is `def __init__(self, group,*args,**kwargs):` so you need to provide the `group` for get and post requests. If you don't pass the `group` for post requests, how can you expect the form to validate the suppliers?

Comment: thanks mate, I am new to web and now I went through methods. I really appreciate your help